# Make webcam work with skype

Tags: 11.10, skype, webcam

Got 11.10 recently and as usual wanted to make Skype video work by doing this

http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/219

Well that used to work for my linux mint 11 installation but now it does not seem to work anymore.

Anyone else got this problem?

Comment: can you start the bash script file in a terminal and see if there is any output like "file not found"?

Comment: fyi. just found this after having the same problem with skype. followed it for Mint 12 and it works...

Comment: Just tried running the file i created and i do get an error saying ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.

Comment: It aint about Linux Mint, Im running Ubuntu 11.10 and the webcam didnt work. It is fixed as mentioned below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahh in 11.10 the path is different

LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/**i386-linux-gnu**/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skype

Now it works

Answer (score 1):

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skype
```

Run the command from terminal window to launch Skype.

Any Webcam works.