# How do I get a SPC 300nc working on a 64-bit system?

Tags: 64-bit, webcam, skype

It seems that [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86384/make-webcam-work-with-skype) solution to webcam problems in Ubuntu 11.10 doesn't work in the 64 bit version.
**If i run the following command:**

```
"LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype"
```

all i get is:

```
"ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored."
```

and if i try:

```
"LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skype"
```

I can't get it to work in ubuntu 12.04 after all. I just installed the beta 2, and installed skype from "partners". No Webcam with either of these tricks :( Tried the 64 bit version from Skype.com but no luck there either.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i fixed it in ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. I installed the lib32v4l-0 package and LD_PRELOAD'ed skype with `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype`

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it in your 12.04 64-bit machine. I installed `lib32v4l-0` and after some time
when I installed Medibuntu from Ubuntu repositories, it removed the 32-bit libs completely, and my sound got completely killed. Only line-in sound works then.

I'm right now trying to solve it without formatting. But I think that formatting will be the solution.

The problem has originated from installing `lib**32**v4l-0` via `apt-get` and then the Medibuntu (package for Ubuntu 12.04 is libv4l-0:i386).

I found a solution to revert the problem arisen. It is in this link http://ubuntuforum-br.org/index.php/topic,52827.msg525995.html#msg525995.

**Note**: It is in Portuguese, use Google translator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems that skype is compiled in 32 bits mode and we were trying to use the 64 bits libraries of video4linux... Or at least that's what I think, I'm not an expert.
You will have to install the 32 bits package with:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32v4l-0
```

After that, this command should run skype with the right orientation of the webcam:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

I hope it works for you as well!

Comment: Thank you! :) When my webcam turns on now, Skype crashes with a SIGBART error though :P But i can confirm that this issue is fixed in 12.04, so it isn't that important ;)